# Бот, который может двигаться по осям

Tags: c#, классы, бот

Чтобы разобраться в классах и их возможностях, хочу написать небольшую игру. Идея создать бота, который будет появляться в точке с заданными координатами и двигаться с определенной скоростью в определенном направлении. Начал писать класс:

```
class bot
{
    public bool fireOn=false; //в дальнейшем хочу научить его стрелять


    public void startmoving(int posX, int posY, int speed)
    {
        //код

    }
}
```

Раньше движение описывал по тику таймера, заставляя двигаться какой-либо объект, например picturebox:

```
 picturebox.Location = new Point(picturebox.Location.X - 1, picturebox.Location.Y);
```

И менять направление движения в зависимости от рандомного числа в следующий тик таймера:

```
Random rnd=new Random();
int i=rnd.Next(1,4);
```

При достижении стенки (границ формы) он менял движение на противоположенное:

```
if (picturebox.Location.X < 1)
        {
            //движется в обратном направлении
        }
```

Но сейчас понимаю, что это далеко нерациональный вариант.
Подскажите простенький вариант реализации такого бота(без всяких наворотов, чисто хаотическое движение в рамках области), спасибо!

Comment: Чем вам этот вариант не понравился? А то может вы и любые другие предложения забракуете. Я вот вижу, что вам вместо проверки на стенки - нужно поставить проверку на выход из заданной области, а направление движения вообще рандомом выбирать.

Comment: Возьмите параметрическое уровнение прямой из "общее уравнение линии (отрезка)" , подставьляйте t - еденицу времени - и получите движение https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F

Comment: @AK Мне кажется, что этот вариант не подходит из-за того, что я его использовал для движения заранее созданных объектов (picturebox), а тут мне нужно чтобы бот в классе создавался.

Comment: Как проще, вот вы записали, чуть перепишу `Location =new  Point(picturebox.Location.X  + dx, picturebox.Location.Y + dy)` задаёте случайные dx,dy - и будет счастье. (или dx=f(t).x и dy=f(t).y где t-рандомное )

Comment: @nick_n_a а как сделать в рамках класса создание объекта? Я хочу реализовать так, чтобы после создания класса я мог бы просто обращатсья к его методу: bot bot1 = new bot();
bot1.startmoving(20, 50, 100); picturebox то в том случае созданный на форме объект

Comment: Как минимум, надо создать приватные поля, и запомнить ваши 20,50,100 в приватных полях т.е. `startMoving(...){ this.posX = postX;...`. А уже как вы хотите реализовать движение - сложно догадаться.

Comment: А как задать в классе создание самого объекта (который и будет двигаться?